# Issue with NSTextView and NSView key events

Tags: macos, cocoa, events, nsview, nstextview

I currently have `NSView` which receives `keyDown:` events and I haven't had any issues with it until trying to implement `NSTextView` with it.

However, I am wanting to handle text input with my application. This way I can utilize various text-like events (`moveUp:`, `moveDown:`, `insertText:`, etc) and give them various uses throughout the application.

After adding `NSTextView` and adding it to the responders via `addSubview:` I have noticed that now, I am no longer getting any `keyDown:` events through `NSView`, but I am getting the `insertText:` events for the text input. If I try to set `acceptsFirstResponder` to `True` for `NSView`, now I can't receive any events from the `NSTextView`, but I do get `keyDown:` events again on the `NSView`.

How do I get these both to work together? I would like receive the above events for the `NSTextView`, as well as the `keyDown:` event from `NSView`. In other words, I want the event to go down the chain of responders (`NSView` and `NSTextView`), how do I go about achieving this? I tried overriding the `keyDown:` of `NSTextView` but it seems once you call `interpretKeyEvents:` it will consume the event and not travel to the `NSView`.

I am not super familiar with cocoa events, but I haven't been able to find a solution to this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the text view and your custom view to both respond to the same key-down events?

Comment: I don't really need the `keyDown:` from the `NSTextView` as the `NSView` can handle it, but if I need both to make it work, then that's fine, I can filter it out manually within the program itself.

Comment: So setting `acceptsFirstResponder` on the `NSView` to `true` solves the issue? Do you call `super` from `keyDown`?

Comment: It only solves the `keyDown/keyUp:` event. I am still not getting the `insertText:` event when I do this. In other words if `NSView` is the first responder, `NSTextView` does not get events, and vise versa. The whole reason I even need `NSTextView` is simply to gather what unicode characters are being inserted/pressed as this information is only loosely supported with `keyDown:` from what I have read.

Comment: Also I need other text-like events such as `insertNewLine:` etc, which only seem to be part of `NSTextView` .

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? How about adopting `NSTextInputClient`?

Comment: Unfortunately the bridge I am using does not support protocols. I however did find a workaround to this issue: By using the events with `nextResponder` on the `NSTextView`, it will then pass it off to `NSView` like I needed. Thanks for your responses.